# Exporting Indexes from Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Are there ways to dump complete indexes from Kibana? I've used ElasticDump but due to our systems if we could also grab indexes from Kibana, that would greatly help. I've struggled to find more direct channels to dump indexes via Kibana. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can register a snapshot repository, then create or update snapshot repository use API.

Reference document:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshots-register-repository.html